# Camera in Roblox Studio (testing and building) is not working correctly

Tags: camera, roblox, roblox-studio

There are actually two camera problems.

The first is that sometimes the RMB to control the camera angle in Studio doesn't work. Sometimes using the LMB or movement keys helps, other times (like right now) it doesn't do anything. The hand cursor appears to shake in the direction I want to pan the camera but nothing happens. I did have an Advanced Camera plugin.

When I'm testing my game in Studio, I have NO camera control via RMB and zooming is nonfunctional. This is to say that I can turn using my mouse, but RMB doesn't change how mouseview works. Probably unrelated, but I cannot get scripts from the toolbox for run, crouch, zoom, etc. to work, either, even when I place them where instructed.

I get these errors in my game:

```
 16:36:47.313   ▼ ActivateCameraController did not select a module. (x3)  -  Client - CameraModule:362
     16:36:47.314     ActivateCameraController did not select a module.
     16:36:47.314     ActivateCameraController did not select a module.
```

I've been having trouble with Studio eating up too much bandwidth when NOT in use during actual gameplay in Roblox (exe), so I removed all the Studio plugins, thinking one of them might be the culprit (deliberate or accidental), and also hoping it might fix the camera issues. No such luck.

Probably unrelated, but I found a couple of apparently simple viruses (Vaccine and Fire) using clone() and spread() to reproduce within the confines that their simple scripts dictated. I removed all instances, as well as a presumably fake Antivirus. The first two were very basic scripts designed to spread the script and didn't do any damage (although the latter would damage players).

Comment: Now that you've turned off all of your plugins, if you open a new Baseplate, are you still seeing these errors when you test the game?

Comment: Good question, @Kylaaa! No, I'm not.

Comment: When I copy-pasted the stuff we'd added in Workspace (but not terrain as I don't know how to copy terrain) into the new one, including the Baseplate, the problem reappeared.

Comment: I added an image of my file structure to the original post. If you'd like to see anything below that level, please let me know.

Comment: you have a malicious script somewhere in your Workspace. You can search/filter the workspace for Script and it will show all of the objects with scripts in them. I would recommend removing or Disabling the each of the scripts until you find which one is causing the errors

Comment: @Kylaaa Thanks, I will search for it. How do I disable a script?

Comment: When you click on a Script in the Explorer, look in the Properties widget. There should be a checkbox titled Disabled. When you select that, it will prevent the script from running when the game starts

Comment: @Kylaaa Thanks again! I'm very grateful for your help!

Comment: @Kylaaa Still looking for the malicious script. Can a script actually affect Studio when you're not simulating it (test/play)?

Comment: @Kylaaa Ok, I went through and disabled ALL scripts, which has caused the camera to function normally when in play mode. However, the RMB still doesn't work when not testing (i.e. while building & scripting).

Comment: I deleted a bunch of stuff my son added, including HD Admin. Aside from one script that was calling a service I didn't understand, I found nothing calling anything external (unless it was obfuscated). I have re-enabled ALL scripts one by one (if they were duplicates, I enabled all instances at once) and the in-game camera problem didn't reoccur, except for once after I paused test mode, edited a script, then resumed. I even ran through the entire game trying to trigger all the unique scripts but the camera worked throughout. RMB Camera in Studio editing mode, however, still doesn't work.

Comment: Sometimes, if the Workspace Camera gets set to Scriptable, all mouse inputs stop working. You could try checking if switching the CameraType to Fixed or anything else fixes your problem. It should be in the Properties window when you select the Camera in the Workspace.

Comment: @Kylaaa FYI, I'm pretty sure that the problem with the Studio camera started when I removed the Advanced Camera Plug-in by yellp1: https://www.roblox.com/library/4631400056/Advanced-Camera. Whatever it was, the problem returns if I use "scriptable."

Answer (score 0):

@Kylaaa came up with the answers, but there's no way for me to mark them as answers.

The problems did not occur in a new game until I copied all the stuff I'd added into it (from the troubled game).

*Regarding RMB not working in the Studio:*

> Sometimes, if the Workspace Camera gets set to Scriptable, all mouse inputs stop working. You could try checking if switching the CameraType to Fixed or anything else fixes your problem. It should be in the Properties window when you select the Camera in the Workspace.

***What I did:*** I changed the mode and the problem stopped. I suspect that the Advanced Camera plug-in that I had removed had something to do with the problem.

*Regarding the camera not zooming and RMB not working during testing:*

> you have a malicious script somewhere in your Workspace. You can search/filter the workspace for Script and it will show all of the objects with scripts in them. I would recommend removing or Disabling the each of the scripts until you find which one is causing the errors

> When you click on a Script in the Explorer, look in the Properties widget. There should be a checkbox titled Disabled. When you select that, it will prevent the script from running when the game starts

***What I did:*** I deleted a bunch of stuff my son had added, and then disabled ALL scripts, then started enabling them one unique instance at a time (i.e. duplicates were enabled simultaneously). The camera problem didn't come back except when I edited a script during testing. I never located the problem script, despite going through and triggering all scripts.